# Add a table in Sharepoint Modern Sites?

Tags: web-part, modern-experience

I'm trying to make a row of 4 buttons, so I want to put them inside a table, all with the same width. But I can't find any web part to put tables. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might want to specify what version of SharePoint you're using in a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a table to a Text web part in SharePoint Online: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-text-and-tables-to-your-page-with-the-Text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801

1. On your page, hover your mouse above or below an existing web part and you'll see a line with a circled +, like this:

[image]

2. Click + and then choose Text from the list of web parts.
3. Click inside the box and the formatting toolbar will display.

[image]

4. Enter your text, and format it using the formatting toolbar. To open or close the Text and table formatting pane, click the ellipses (...) on the right side on the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @CarlF, I was hoping there was a table to add "button webparts" inside of it.. So I guess all I can do for now is adding a text webpart, then a table and put the buttons as hyperlinks

Comment: If you want a rectangular grid of buttons, the Hero and Quick Links web parts provide that. They just aren't called "table".

Comment: I expected to see a table to add any webparts inside, like it was on "normal" sharepoint pages... because I want to be able to make my own grids of 4, 5 columns, but I guess I'll have to adapt to this or the webpart you propose

Comment: @SoulEeater, SharePoint Modern pages do support columns, so you can hand-build a grid of web parts, although it wouldn't be an HTML table and I don't believe you can do 5 columns natively. Microsoft consciously doesn't give SharePoint designers as much freedom as someone who hand-codes (or uses other tools).